# Why does some bacon contain whey powder?

Tags: additives

I wouldn't expect bacon to contain cows milk, but it does in some cases in the form of whey powder. What's the purpose of it?

(My daughter is allergic to cow's milk and I have to check her foods carefully, including bacon, which isn't a food I'd expect to contain dairy.)

Comment: I wouldn't either.. it's there to make you pay for cheap  whey powder, instead of expensive meat, whatever the claimed rationale. Buy better bacon, and eat less of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Whey powder is often used in processed meats](https://www.thinkusadairy.org/Documents/Customer%20Site/C3-Using%20Dairy/C3.7-Resources%20and%20Insights/03-Application%20and%20Technical%20Materials/PROCESSEDMEATS_ENG.pdf) for bulking and binding.  In the case of whole muscles, they are often injected with a brine (an ingredient of which is whey protein) to "enhance moisture and tenderness", as the document states.  I could also imagine it as a binding agent in turkey "bacon", where ground turkey is formed and sliced.